# Cocoa warning: NSWindow does not support utility styleMask 0x10

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I have re-drawn the `NSWindow`, and now when I start my app there is a warning in the console that says `NSWindow does not support utility styleMask 0x10`.   How can I get rid of this warning?

Any idea?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it said `0x10` and not `0x1000`?

Comment: yes,I sure it said 0X10,not 0X100.you can see the screenshot.

Comment: You're not the first. A handful of relevant threads, two from Cocoa-dev, one from MacRumors' programming forum: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2007/Nov/msg02228.html http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2008/Jun/msg00482.html http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=520053

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`NSUtilityWindowMask` is a bit (0x10) in the `styleMask` property of a `NSPanel` which is not supported by `NSWindow`.

If you have created this in an xib, then you should be able to change the custom class to `NSPanel`, uncheck the `utility mask` checkbox and then change it back.  If you did it in code, (or are changing the `styleMask` property in code) make sure that you are not setting bit 0x10 of `styleMask`.

Comment: Can't find the checkbox. I assume, as of Xcode 7 this is the "Style" drop down menu for NSPanel ("Regular Panel" / "Utility Panel" / "HUD Panel"). However, can not find a single window that is set to that in my whole project...

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer valid.  Any ideas what to do to fix this?